# ContentControls referencing the same StaticResource only render the resource once

Tags: wpf

I have a resource in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="Icons.Profile">
    <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="40.7907" Height="33.55" Canvas.Left="16.2093" Canvas.Top="22.2" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M ... "/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

If I add two Buttons/Content Controls that reference the StaticResource only the one rendered last seems to render the "Icon"

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Icons.Profile}" />
```

Does anyone know why and how I can get around this?  In Visual Studio and Blend the Content is being rendered for all controls.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because a element can only have 1 logical parent, however you can set your resource to `x:Shared="false"` and this will create/render a new element for each use.

Example:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="Icons.Profile" x:Shared="false">
    <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="40.7907" Height="33.55" Canvas.Left="16.2093" Canvas.Top="22.2" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M ... "/>
    </Canvas> 
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thanks. So easy yet googlebing did not bring me this solution!

Comment: YAY! And so nice of the XAML Editor to lie to me and show it multiple times when it was never going to be that way.